# How did Latias transform in Pokémon Heroes?

Tags: pokemon

In the movie *Pokémon Heroes* Latias is able to transform into Bianca (a human character in the movie). [Serebii.net](http://serebii.net/pokedex-xy/380.shtml), however, does not list transform as a move Latias can use. Were any comments made in the movie regarding the transformation? Is Latias using the move transform or is it using some other power?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Latias_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#In_the_manga), in the *Pokémon Adventures* manga, Latias is also able to appear as a human by using its ability to refract light. This is consistent with its Pokédex entry in the Sapphire game:

> [The POKéMON enfolds its body with its down and refracts light to alter its appearance.](http://serebii.net/pokedex-rs/380.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

Latias transformed into bianca because she was bianca best friend so she transformed into her giving him opportunity to hug ash.but at the end if this movie it was bianca even the writer said she did not talked to confuse ash just kiss and ran away

Comment: Citing or providing a relevant quote from the writer would greatly improve your answer.